# Django Forms Set Name Of The Form

Tags: html, django, forms, django-forms, attributes

How can I set the **name of the form** with model form ?

This is my model form :

```
class DetayModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = Detay
    fields = [ 'yazi', 'tip', 'kullanimAdet']
```

I know how to set name attribute of a **field** in a form, *there are a lot of examples also*.

But I really really couldn't find that how can I set the form's own name , **not a field in the form**, exactly form's own name attribute; in the ModelForm class.

In html side , I will use this attribute : https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_name.asp

I need to use html form **name** attribute in my template but, I couldn't find how to add this attribute to the form directly in ModelForm class.

I tried to use init in ModelForm class like that :

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.name = 'DetayFormu'
```

But in html side, still form doesn't have a name attribute.

And also I know , yes I can set this attribute in my template like that :

```
<form method="post" name="DetayFormu">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form|crispy }}
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

> But I really wonder how can I set this attribute **in ModelForm class
>   directly**.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use helper attr to add any new attributes

```
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
class DetayModelForm(forms.ModelForm):  
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_action = 'url'
        super(DetayModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper.attrs = {'name': 'DetayFormu','autocomplete':'off'}
  class Meta:
    model = Detay
    fields = [ 'yazi', 'tip', 'kullanimAdet']
```